# Can you download/access your Android app signing key from Google Play Console if you let Google manage keys?

Tags: android, key, apk, google-console-developer

Unfortunately I believe that I have lost the local copy of the key used to sign my Android app package. When uploading/using Google Play Console I would have allowed Google to manage all my keys. My question is whether it is possible to obtain a copy of the key from Google to replace my lost local copy?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a copy of your key, however Google allows you to reset your key, i.e. create a new one and provide them with the certificate. After they verify your identity, you'll be able to upload new APKs/App Bundles signed with your new upload key.

See section **Create a new upload key** at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423,

Answer (score 1):

### Fortunately I found that I had (sensibly) backed up my keys after all - panic over! However before I got to that point I had some helpful response from Google which may help anyone else with a similar problem:

Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.
I’m happy to help you reset your upload key, but please specify the package name of the apps you are referring to before I can proceed further. The new upload key will be used to sign APKs that you upload to Play.

Here’s how to generate and register a new upload key:
Follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center to generate a new key. It must be different from any previous keys. Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a new key:
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
This key must be a 2048 bit RSA key and have 25-year validity.
Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
Reply to this email and attach the upload_certificate.pem file.

### Kindly let me know which app you would like reset with the new upload key

Answer (score 0):

If you used Google Play signing, you had to sign your APK with an upload key, and then Google signed it with the definitive key. This means that if you lost your upload key you can contact Google Play support and provide a new upload key.